# How to Deploy smart contracts to different chains in Eris (Monax)

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, eris-blockchain

I have problem with Eris (Monax). I follow the tutorial of Eris
https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

All is good. I'm successful to create,  instantiate a Blockchain called simplechain, and deploy a smart contract called idi (exactly in tutorial)

Now I want to create another chain, called simplechain3 so that 2 chains can run at the same time, and then, I want to deploy this contract idi or another contract (if I want to create the new one) this new chain simplechain3.
I can create new simplechain3 but I cannot deploy this contract or another contract to this new chain simplechain3. It always aims at the old chain simplechain.

Here are commands I typed:
*eris chains make --account-types=Root:3,Full:2 simplechain3*

*eris chains start simplechain3 --init-dir simplechain3_full_000 --ports=1428,47000,47001*

(I must create new ports for this chain. If not, the error will appears because the port 46657 was already occupie by the old simplechain)

All is good, I checked it by this command
*eris chains ls*
Output:
*CHAIN            ON     CONTAINER ID     DATA CONTAINER
simplechain3     *      b4cecde58c       965309c59f
simplechain      *      e3868c82b0       38dd9d37fa*

With this command:
*docker ps*

Output
*CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                        NAMES
b4cecde58cfb        quay.io/eris/db:0.12.0     "eris-db serve"          35 seconds ago      Up 33 seconds       0.0.0.0:1428->1337/tcp, 0.0.0.0:47000->46656/tcp, 0.0.0.0:47001->46657/tcp   simplechain3-422e5ebf-6149-46d7-963d-ddbb33104ac4
e3868c82b07d        quay.io/eris/db:0.12.0     "eris-db serve"          19 hours ago        Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp, 0.0.0.0:46656-46657->46656-46657/tcp                 simplechain-7f87110d-1323-4c97-bc70-a0ae971c4960
18f16072cb1f        quay.io/eris/keys:0.12.0   "eris-keys server --h"   19 hours ago        Up 44 minutes       4767/tcp                                                                     keys-b46408a1-fe29-4205-ac51-878b487d8f78*

Then, other commands
*chain_dir_3=$HOME/.eris/chains/simplechain3
chain_dir_this_3=$chain_dir_3/simplechain3_full_000
addr3=$(cat $chain_dir_3/addresses.csv | grep simplechain3_full_000 | cut -d ',' -f 1)
eris pkgs do --chain simplechain3 --address $addr3 --file ./epm.yaml
*

Output with error:

*Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Executing Job                                 defaultAddr
Executing Job                                 setStorageBase
Executing Job                                 deployStorageK
Response                                  abi=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"}]
                                          bin=606060405260978060106000396000f360606040526000357c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009004806360fe47b11460415780636d4ce63c14605757603f565b005b605560048080359060200190919050506078565b005b606260048050506086565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b806000600050819055505b50565b600060006000505490506094565b9056
                                         name=IdisContractsFTW
Deploying Contract                       name=IdisContractsFTW
**Encountered error waiting for event: timed out waiting for event**
                                         addr=796AA808A90DFA52D2502CFCA7803BFBBDC030CD
Executing Job                                 setStorage
Deprecation Warning: The use of the 'data' field to specify the name of the contract function has been deprecated. Please update your epm jobs file to utilize a combination of 'function' and 'data' fields instead. See documentation for further details.
**Encountered error waiting for event: timed out waiting for event**
Executing Job                                 queryStorage
Deprecation Warning: The use of the 'data' field to specify the name of the contract function has been deprecated. Please update your epm jobs file to utilize a combination of 'function' and 'data' fields instead. See documentation for further details.
**Error connnecting to node (tcp://chain:46657) to query contract at (796AA808A90DFA52D2502CFCA7803BFBBDC030CD) with data (6D4CE63C)%!(EXTRA string=Account 796aa808a90dfa52d2502cfca7803bfbbdc030cd does not exist)**
Could not perform pkg action service: Could not perform pkg action: Container interactive-808a8aa8-09cb-4b9f-ae3a-b77158681c21 exited with status 1*

Could you help me solve this problem? How to deploy the contract to another chain? I've already tested it with another contract, it is the same.

The content of the file epm.yaml is in the tutorial
https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#step-3-2-fixup-your-epm-yaml

And the content of the contract is in the tutorial, too
https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#step-3-1-make-a-contract-for-idi

For the another contract, the same problems appears.

I work in Linux Ubuntu 16.04, Eris 0.12.0, docker 1.12.3

Thanks a lot

Comment: I also type the command
eris pkgs do --chain simplechain3 --address $addr3 --chain-port 47001 --file ./epm.yaml

and receive error
Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Error connecting to node (tcp://chain:47001) to get chain id: Post http://chain:47001: dial tcp 172.17.0.4:47001: getsockopt: connection refused

Could not perform pkg action service: Could not perform pkg action: Container interactive-7c31b92d-9981-4d12-b6c9-e55fe63f33fe exited with status 1

47001 is a port I use to start this chain

Comment: I also type the command
eris pkgs do --chain simplechain3 --address $addr3 --chain-port 47001 

and receive error
Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Error connecting to node (tcp://chain:47001) to get chain id: Post http://chain:47001: dial tcp 172.17.0.4:47001: getsockopt: connection refused

Could not perform pkg action service: Could not perform pkg action: Container interactive-7c31b92d-9981-4d12-b6c9-e55fe63f33fe exited with status 1

47001 is a port I use to start this chain When I type ifconfig, I discover that my IPadress is 172.17.0.2, not 172.17.0.4 above

Comment: When I type ifconfig, I discover that my IPadress is 172.17.0.2, not 172.17.0.4 above

Comment: I have just created a simplechain2 with only one full node and multiple root nodes and run on ports 1628, 38000, 50000
It works. The contract is deployed with success using this command above

The chains simplechain3 has 2 full node. Maybe the command eris pkgs do of the current version eris 0.12 donot take it into account?